# Automate memory search in dump

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dump

I have full dump and want to search across custom made doubly linked list of 6+ millions elements.

To make is simple consider that element of list contains data that is type integer.
Is that way to find (automate) if there is element with specific value.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Professional, so action "Debug Managed Memory" is not an option.

Comment: Just to confirm. You want do it with C++?

Comment: Dump is for project made in C++. And I wont to automate search in any possible way.

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by "list"? is it a `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::array`, or just a `[]` array? Do you already know where in memory that list is, or don't you? How did you arrive there? Can you provide a [mre] so we can discuss better and show a solution for a concrete problem? Do you have symbols or not? Is it a kernel dump or a user mode dump? Do you want to search for one specific element only, or a sequence of elements?

Comment: It's custom made list, updated

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! You could click '✔' to mark it as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have used WinDbg Preview tool to sovlve this. It's free tool made by Microsoft.
It can run JavaScript to analyze memory, and probably much more.

Template JS code list iteration :

```
"use strict";

function read_next(addr) {
    return host.memory.readMemoryValues(addr, 1, 8)[0];
}

function read_data(addr) {
    return host.memory.readMemoryValues(addr + 0x10, 1, 8)[0];
}

function invokeScript() {
    let current = 0x123; // hardcoded

    while(current)
    {
        let data = read_data(current);

        // use data pointer to analize data

        current = read_next(current);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer does not explain how it is solved. It just mentions the tool to use - which was already mentioned by OP (yourself) as a tag in the question. As it stands, this answer is not useful. Anyone coming here will still not know how to do an automatic memory search.

Comment: You are right, tag was added to question after solving it. It is removed to avoid confusing.
JS template added.